# Strange null string concatenation behaviour

Tags: c#, string, string-concatenation

I have a code concatenating two string using plus operator. If two strings are null, sum of two strings is not null.

```
var strLeft = default(string);
var strRight = default(string);

var strSum = strLeft + strRight;
```

I want to distinguish String.Empty + default(string) and default(string) + default(string). Both concat operation result is String.Empty.

Why results of both total are String.Empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because null string is treated as empty string [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx):

> In string concatenation operations, the C# compiler treats a null string the same as an empty string, but it does not convert the value of the original null string

Comment: Thans. I will write a special string concat method.

Answer (score 4):

The `+` operator calls on string arguments are translated by the C# compiler to calls to the  [`string.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wkb0y3w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. And here's what the documentation of this method states:

> An Empty string is used in place of any null argument.

So basically that's by design. The `string.Concat` method will never return null.

Comment: Emphasis: the `+` is handled by the compiler and this is not something you could achieve for your own class by overloading `operator+`

Comment: Yes, precisely. That's what I mentioned in my first sentence. The `+` operator is translated by the C# compiler to calls to the string.Concat method.